Mock jproperties config in pytest
I am using python jproperties to read a properties file (https://pypi.org/project/jproperties/).
config_loc = "application.properties"
with open(config_loc, 'rb') as config_file:
    configs.load(config_file)

The properties file looks something like this:
abc=xyz
jhg=123

I am writing pytests and am trying to mock the config data using unittest.mock. The pytest looks something like this:
mocked_content = b'abc=xyz'
with patch('builtins.open', mock_open(read_data=mocked_content)):
    # Call to the script where "with open(config_loc, 'rb')" call is made

With this, I get the following exception:
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

As I understand, patch is expecting a string where as jproperties is expecting bytes. The code below works for jproperties:
mocked_content = b'abc=xyz'
configs = Properties()
configs.load(BytesIO(mocked_content))

What I am unable to find is a way to pass bytes using unittest.mock. How will I be able to do this?
